Problema de versiones
Hola estoy terminando un proyecto de microservicios e-ecommerce y estoy teniedo un problema con flyway y postgresql.El error que me aparece es :

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class
path resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL 16.3
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported
Database: PostgreSQL 16.3

La version que estoy utilizando en mi docker-compose es la version 16.3 y la de flyway la 10.17.0

Debes usar una versiòn anterior de PostgreSQL ya que esta no esta soportada, usa una versiòn entre 12.0 a 16.0

Según tengo entendido, Flyway "10.17" no es compatible con PostgreSQL "16.3".
La compatibilidad con Postgresql solo llega hasta la versión "16.0".

El mensaje

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class
path resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL 16.3
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported
Database: PostgreSQL 16.3

indica que el problema radica entre la version PostgreSQL 16.3 y la version Flyway 10.17.0, esta es la tabla de compatibilidad:

Te sugiero uses PostgreSQL versiòn 12.0 a 16.0

Use la version de flyway la 10.17.0 y la version de postgresql 12.19 , me sigue tirando el mismo error. Esta es mi configuracion de product-service.yml : 
la dependencia 
